# How to convert SQL syntax into Mongo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I use Ruby on Rails and Mongoid

How to convert this syntax to make it work with Mongo?

```
def index
  @conversations = Conversation.where("sender_id = ? OR receiver_id = ?", current_user.id, current_user.id)
end
```

and

```
def index
  @conversation.messages.where("user_id != ? AND read = ?", current_user.id, false).update_all(read: true)
end
```

Comment: Essentially you are asking how run a sql query on a non-sql db. fundamentally they both work differently hence it's damm difficult to have a converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution:

```
@conversations = Conversation.where("sender_id = ? OR receiver_id = ?", current_user.id, current_user.id)
```

**change to**

```
@conversations = Conversation.any_of({sender_id: current_user.id}, {receiver_id: current_user.id})
```

The second line had to be completely rewritten and not used. So I don't know if it works or not

```
@conversation.messages.where("user_id != ? AND read = ?", current_user.id, false).update_all(read: true)
```

**may not work**

```
@conversation.messages.not.where(user_id: current_user.id).where(read: false).update_all(read: true)
```

Comment: The second line was supposed to find messages where user_id is NOT the current user, though?